# PHP using STRPOS to find partial value in CLASS

Tags: php, strpos

I need to search inside a string to find if there ise any matches to this pattern:

```
class="%men%"
```

It means that the class may be equal to either:

```
class="men"
class="mainmen"
class="MyMen" 
class="menSuper"
class="MyMenSuper"
```

etc

I need someting like `strpos($string,'class="%men%')` where % could be anything.

Best,
Martti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using preg_match

```
if (preg_match("/men/i", $class)) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

Look at this link for more information http://www.php.net/preg_match

**Edit :**

So you can do like this (Inspired from the answer of Marius.C)

```
$string = '<div class="menlook">Some text</div>';
if (preg_match('/class="(.*)men(.*)"/i', $string)) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but It does not do the job. I have a string that contains HTML data. That means there may be text or other elements that includes men. I only need to find if class inside this HTML string contains men.

Answer (score 2):

Store class "men" as string in variable like "$your_class"

then use preg_match like this:

`if(preg_match('/men/i', $your_class)) {
  echo "Men Class Found!";
}`

ref: http://php.net/preg_match

or using strpos:

`if(strpos(strtolower($your_class),'men')!==false) {
  echo "Men Class Found!";
}`

ref: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strpos.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use `strpos` two times,

```
if(strpos($string,'class=') !== false && strpos($string,'men') !== false){
   echo "true";
}
```

**Note:** `strpos` is much faster than `preg_match`.

Comment: And if we have `<div class="test">I'm going to the mensroom</div>` as $string?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible without regular expressions which are quite slow

```
stristr($string, 'men')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need something like this:

`preg_match_all('/class="(.*)men(.*)"/i', $string, $matches);`